# How to use Spring roo with for PURE spring MVC services?

Tags: spring, spring-roo

I'm about to rebuild an existing app almost from scratch and i would like to use spring Roo to gain productivity.

The app will be composed of two parts:

1. A web backend which will be a pure REST web service backend.
2. A single page rich js frontend with backbonejs.

I've been able to start generating the structure of the app and many nice set up has been made. however when i scaffolded the web layer, i got a bunch of views/tags/tiles that has been generated for me.
I see also many seetings/dependencies that has been added too.

Now the issue is i don't want all those stufs and i want to get rid of them.

When i suppress a few of them i'm not able to use Roo anymore as all scafolding are disabled.

Any clue on what should i due??

Answer (score 1):

First off, you dont have to use scaffolding.  You can just create blank Controllers.  You can also remove the scaffolded controllers you don't want.  the Roo Shell will detect when you delete one, and should clean up all the "settings/dependencies".

The one thing that I like to point out to people is that the scaffolded controllers do follow a RESTful paradigm.  It actually follows it quite strictly.  I personally like using the scaffolding to setup a base app, then I start slashing-and-burning the stuff I don't want out.  For instance, removing the menu on the left.  Also, I prefer JSON over straight web calls, so I usually add that.  Spring Roo magically converts all the Controllers to do both standard and JSON REST calls.

If you want to switch to using some other framework, I don't think there is anything stopping you.  It sort of defeats the purpose of using Roo, unless all you wanted was the Entity beans.    I personally use jQuery.js in addition to dojo.js (the default).  All of the UI components are implemented as a combination of JSPs and custom tags all controlled by Apache Tiles.  For instance, to add/change/remove script tags loaded on all the pages, look at the load-scripts.tagx.  I think you will find it's pretty easy to add custom JS to use on the UI side.